Я хочу создать умный дом на C++. Что использовать?
недавно, я начал учить с++.
хочу написать первый проект (сложный).
с++ мой третий язык.
думаю написать умный дом.
используя еще raspberry pi3.
у меня функции будут такие:

включение/выключение светодиодной ленты + настройка цветов

распознавание человека(на случай если он входит в комнату, выполнять какое-то действие, например включать звуки природы)

прослушивание микрофона и выполнение действий по командам(по сути голосовой помощник)


подскажите, какие технологии лучше всего использовать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Для новичков, которые хотят спроектировать умный дом, на мой взгляд, стоит обратить внимание на простенькую Arduino. Еще можно купить модуль ESP8266 (самый популярный модуль Wifi), чтобы можно было управлять дистанционно. И еще на библиотеку RemoteXY, на ней можно сделать интерфейс для управления с приложения RemoteXY и управлять wifi модулем, который будет общаться с ардуинкой и на пример включать свет.

Для начала, я бы использовал микроконтроллеры arduino, такие, как mega, nano, uno, attiny, или если нужно подключение к wifi - esp32 или esp8266, тк использовать raspberry в умном доме это немного пушкой по воробью.
Для программирования можно использовать такие проги, как arduinoIDE, avrStudio или даже codeBlocks.
У Алекса Гайвера есть много реализаций разных идей. Вот про модули умного дома: https://alexgyver.ru/modules/
У него же на ютубе есть много уроков по разным тонкостям использования arduino и esp-шек
